# Why wont the context.restore() set the scale of the context back to (1, 1)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making an HTML5 game engine, and I want my `Camera` object to have a `zoom` property. In the renderer, I thought that I could easily implement it, like this:

```
context.save();
context.scale(camera.zoom, camera.zoom);
draw();
context.restore();
```

There is a problem, though. When I first tested this, the camera seemed to zoom forever! I figured that `context.save()` and `context.restore()` probably aren't working as expected, and that the context's internal scaling factor is getting multiplied by camera's `zoom` ad infinitum.

This fixed the situation:

```
context.save();
context.scale(camera.zoom, camera.zoom);
draw();
context.scale(1/camera.zoom, camera.zoom);
context.restore();
```

This works now, but I'm afraid that this isn't the most elegant/fast solution. Also, I think it is possible that, because of the floating point calculation imprecision, the scaling factor always changes slightly. That is, `1/camera.zoom` might not always produce the same results.

So, two questions:

1. Why wont the context.restore() set the scale of the context back to (1, 1)?
2. How can I manually manipulate the scaling of the context?

---

Edit:

It was pointed out that the number of `context.save()`'s and `context.restore()`'s might be different, but that is not the case.

Here is how I measured it:

```
renderer.context.save = (function()
{
    var original = renderer.context.save;

    return function()
    {
        renderer.saved ++;
        original.call(renderer.context);
    }
})();

renderer.context.restore = (function()
{
    var original = renderer.context.restore;

    return function()
    {
        renderer.saved --;
        original.call(renderer.context);
    }
})();
```

The `renderer.saved` value is `1` right before the context is restored one last time (after draw), and `0` after each rendering.

Comment: Does `draw` happen to save more states than it restores? As it stands, it works fine for me without scaling back: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBNG9/.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: Strangely, now, the number of saves and restores is equivalent after each rendering. Please see my edit, I described how I measured that.

Comment: Is it zero after `draw`? You state it is one after the context has been restored the last time, but that would seem wrong (when is it set to zero then?).

Comment: Damn, that was a typo. Corrected now! (It is `1` after `draw`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I have accidentally solved the problem. It works now.

The main suspect is this part of the code:

```
renderer.context.save();

//Erase everything.
renderer.context.globalAlpha = 1;
renderer.context.fillStyle = renderer.settings.fillStyle;
renderer.context.fillRect(0, 0, renderer.width, renderer.height);

//Zoom.
renderer.context.scale(camera.zoom, camera.zoom);
```

I believe that I used to zoom before actually saving the context, resulting in restoring having no effect on the zoom.